# Запятая при однородных членах: "творческие(,) оригинальные работы"

Tags: запятые, однородные-члены

Считаю, что нужна запятая: *наличие творческих(,) оригинальных работ* - характеризуют предмет с одной стороны: оригинальные работы, поэтому их и можно считать творческими. Так ли я рассуждаю, или не нужна запятая?

Comment: @Верьясова, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 3):

Думаю, Вы абсолютно правы

Answer (score 0):

Появление красивой интонационной творческой оригинальной запятой - по желанию автора.